# How do you write a Wordpress function to put a Span around the first word of the Title?

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I want to replace first word in title to have `<span></span>` inside.

Example for Wordpress title

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#">Welcome to Wordpress</a></h2>
```

I want to be like this

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#"><span>Welcome</span> to Wordpress</a></h2>
```

the function

```
function span_on_title($span) {
 return preg_replace('', '', $span, 1);
}
add_filter('the_title','span_on_title');
```

May i know what to put on the `preg_replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $title = '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#">Welcome to Wordpress</a></h2>';

  $title = preg_replace('/<a([^>]+)>([a-zA-Z]+)\s/i', '<a$1><span>$2</span> ', $title);

  return $title;
```

Comment: hmmm.. nothing change when I put the code. I've update `the_title` format with hyperlink

Comment: @Michael - Not as you wrote it ;) ... You are missing `$title` as the 3rd argument of `preg_replace` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php ) - working example ==> http://codepad.org/LHkvfNIf

Comment: @Michael actually this one worked, but need modify all template which have the `the_title()`. BTW thanks give me a clue. Good example.

Comment: No problem, happy to be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php file in your theme:

```
// Adds span around the first word of post titles
if ( ! is_admin(false) ) {
add_action('brentini_span_post_title');
function brentini_span_post_title($span_title) {
$span_title = preg_replace('/(^[A-z0-9_]+)\s/i', '<span>$1</span> ', $span_title);
return $span_title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'brentini_span_post_title');
} 
elseif ( ! is_admin(true) ) {
remove_filter('the_title', 'brentini_span_post_title');
}
```

The output on the frontend for instance, will look like this:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#"><span>Welcome</span> to Wordpress</a></h2>
```

But it won't be affected on the backend while viewing the posts table.

And then you can style it in your style.css like this for instance:

```
h2.entry-title span {color:#0531C2}
```

**EDIT:** added if else statement to adjust formatting for frontend theme only without adjusting backend theme. Seems to work just fine. If there is a better way, I'd love to hear it, Thanks!