# Revised Wordpress function to put a Span around the first word of the Title?

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to use a function that adds a "span" around the first word of every post title in a Wordpress site, and found [this extremely similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507003/how-do-you-write-a-wordpress-function-to-put-a-span-around-the-first-word-of-the) question. The function in the second answer works fine when there's a link inside the H2 element.

But In my site, I'm not using the post title as a link, so the found solution doesn't work. I've tried to come up with a new preg-replace pattern, as to skip the detection of the link part, but haven't been able to get it.

Basically, I want this:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> or <h2>Converted post title</h2>
```

... to become this:

```
<h2><span>Converted</span> post title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do that using woodpress hooks and filter. so that you can use the_title() function without additional code.

put this code into functions.php in your theme folder. that's all.

```
    function add_label_to_post_title( $title = '' ) {
       if(trim($title) != "")
       {
      $ARR_title = explode(" ", $title);
      
      if(sizeof($ARR_title) > 1 )
          {
             $first_word = "<span>".$ARR_title['0']."</span>";
             unset($ARR_title['0']);
             return $first_word. implode(" ", $ARR_title);
          }
          else
          {
              return "<span>{$title}</span>";
          }
       }
       return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );
```

Comment: That would output `<h2><span>Converted</span> Converted post title</h2>`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I've modified the function for you. that's should work now.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! However, there's two issues still. I think in line 8, the last span should be a closing one. The other thing is that when implemented, many other elements in the template (not only h2) get the effect applied. In fact, it creates several new h2 elements.

Comment: @Sergio Majluf its depends on template loop. In the loop already had the <h2> tags you can remove <h2> from above code. and that's should be ok.

Comment: @FazleElahee as Sergio mentioned - pls close the span in line 8. THX

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
if(substr($title,0)>-1){
    $first_word = substr($title,0,strpos($title," "));
    $after_that = substr($title,strpos($title," ")+1);
}else{
    $first_word = $title;
    $after_that = "";
}
echo "<span>".$first_word."</span> " . $after_that;
?>
```

Comment: And I've updated it for single-word titles. Thanks @LawrenceCherone.

Comment: You should add the space to the after_that variable so single words don't get an extra space added to the end

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do that in javascript so you could lessen the processing/cpu use of the server. You would still have the same result.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('h2.title').each( function (){
            var obj_h2 = $(this);
            var h2_title = obj_h2.html();
            var words = h2_title.split(' ');
            words[0] = '<span>' + words[0] + '</span>'

            obj_h2.html( words.join( ' ' ) );
        } );
    });
</script>
```

https://gist.github.com/2440296#file_h2_span1stw_2.htm

*Previous code version..
https://gist.github.com/2440296#file_h2_span1stw.htm
http://jsbin.com/uguhel/edit#html,live

Comment: if you want to `lessen the processing/cpu` you wouldn't use wordpress ;p

Comment: Thanks @fedmich. So far, this is my preferred answer, although it's not through functions and pre-replace wich was what I expected, it's the most useful so far because I only have to code it once and include it everywhere, without further altering my templates.

Comment: Hello again @fedmich. This implementation sets an odd limit. Once an H2 element is selected, and it's html content replaced, every H2 present in the document inherit the same html content, i.e. they all  render the same text inside. Is there a work around?

Comment: Hmm, so you plan to use it on multiple h2 tags it seems, thats a different case, I'll make another variation for this then. hold on :)